# Spring Boot WebFlux remove Whitelabel

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

I am testing the new WebFlux framework and I would like to remove the default error view (Whitelabel Error Page). I have noticed that the default server for this framework is `Netty` and that it seems not to respond to the old `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false`.

Is there any other way or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug and it will be fixed in Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE, see [gh-12520](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12520).

In the meantime, you could:

- exclude completely the `ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration` if you don't want any Spring Boot error handling support
- add a error template/static file in your application to override the default view

Note that once it's supported (and without applying the other options I've just listed), your application will just send a raw HTTP error response (i.e. **not a JSON response**). Is that what you intend to have?

Comment: Thks Brian, after looking at the source code I saw that is somehow hardcoded, you either have text/html or json. I am interested in a json only repsonse as my app will be a rest backend. Is there any way to switch only to json error response?

Comment: Unless the HTTP client asks explicitly for `text/html`, the error will be sent as JSON. Wouldn't that work in your case?

Comment: Yes it would, but I would rather hide that view and respond with json to all requests.

Comment: In that case you can define your own WebExceptionHandler as seen here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-webflux-error-handling and override the routing function to always write the response as JSON

Comment: That's perfect, I will try that. Thanks again Brian.